# Load timeout in Rails's Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin (https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) for Rails, and am trying to load the index view of my User model. Here's the code in my app/admin/users.rb file:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
    config.per_page = 10

    index :pagination_total => false do
    end
end
```

I have pagination enabled, but it looks like it's still trying to load all of the users, resulting in a timeout. How do I get it to load only a few (e.g. 10) users at a time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things you could try to improve performance on your pages:

1. Try disabling the count from any scopes you might have:

   ```
   scope :active, show_count: false
   ```
2. Try disabling filters you don't need

   ```
   config.filters = false #or simply specify the ones you do need
   ```
3. Avoid n+1 queries by eager loading any associated models

   ```
   controller do
     def scoped_collection
       resource_class.includes(:brownies)
     end
   end
   ```

Hope this helps.